# threading a network stream write from same socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

```
byte [] buffer = new byte [4];
buffer = "AAA";
this.networkStream.Write(buffer , 0 , 4);
this.networkStream.Flush();
```

Can I start multiple threads all using the same socket to send a stream through a socket simultaneously?

If I have two threads, one is sending a buffer of 4 characters AAA and the other thread is BBB

Will the data at the other end look like AAABBB or mixed letters ABABAB?

Comment: Any mix you like may be possible, but the most likely outcome is AAABBB or BBBAAA.  More complex mixes become possible when the tx stack buffers get full and one, or the other, or both, get blocked and do not get to tarnsfer all their string in one go.  To avoid this, you could queue the strings to one thread that does all the sending.

Comment: I'll look into how queue my BackgroundWorkers from access the same method. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for `NetworkStream` states:

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an
>   instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for
>   synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write
>   operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will
>   be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

So no, you should not have more than one thread writing to the stream at the same time. You really feel the need to have more than one writer then you will need to synchronize access to the stream via a `lock` (or some other mechanism). However, if you do this then you will be effectively writing to the stream in a serial fashion so why not simplify things and just structure your code so that there actually is only one writer.

It is pretty easy to use a pattern with one writer by taking advantage of the `BlockingCollection` class. Here is a simple example that demonstrates how this might be done.

```
public class Example
{
  private NetworkStream networkstream = GetNetworkStream();
  private BlockingCollection<byte[]> queue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

  public Example()
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
      () =>
      {
        foreach (byte[] buffer in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
          this.networkstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
      }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
  }

  public void QueueWrite(byte[] buffer)
  {
    queue.Add(buffer);
  }
}
```